# PowerShell - Execute MySQL with Parameters

Tags: mysql, powershell

I'm trying to run a script to output some records from MySQL, however when I try and run the script it's displaying the MySQL help file, I think the parameters are not being passed to the program correctly.

Here is the script

```
$path_to_MySQL = "C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql.exe"

$param1 = "-h XXX"
$param2 = "-D XXX"  
$param3 = "-u XXX"
$param4 = "-pXXX"
$param5 = "-e ""SELECT 'Test';"""

$params = @($param1, $param2, $param3, $param4, $param5)

write-host $path_to_MySQL $params

&$path_to_MySQL $params
```

Now this outputs to the display,

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql.exe -h XXX -D XXX -u XXX -pXXX -e "SELECT 'Test';"
ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host ' XXX'
```

The first line is because of the `write-host` line.

However, when I copy the output from here and run it straight in the console, it runs correctly. (i.e. I have the correct host details)

How can I run this line using the PowerShell Script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you using as server name? Pay attention to the error message: `Unknown MySQL server host ' XXX'`, which quotes the host name as `' XXX'` (note the space) instead of `'XXX'`.

One gotcha in Powershell is that double quote `"` strings are evaluated whereas single quote `'` strings are not. So if your host name contains special characters, Powershell might mess 'em up. That is,

```
$foo="foo"

# This will print
# foo walked in bar
"$foo walked in bar"

# This will print:
# $foo walked in bar
'$foo walked in bar'
```

Try a workaround like so,

```
$param1 = '-h XXX'
$param2 = '-D XXX'
$param3 = '-u XXX'
```

And

```
&$path_to_MySQL $param1 $param2 $param3
```

Comment: I do have the correct host names. But I expanded on what you suggested and I have it working. It didn't like when I combined "-h XXX" into the same param. When I seperated it as `&$path_to_MySQL "-h" $param1 "-D" $param2 "-y" $param3` it worked fine.